# Information on how to do git revisioning for yocto

Tags: git, embedded-linux, yocto

We have customized based Intel board and planning to use Yocto for Embedded Linux Development.

Can you please provide information on how to proceed for versioning.. Do we need to download tarball  of yocto layers and then create our own board layer and then add everything to git repo.

How to support upstream, I mean if new Yocto branch is released.. How to upload the latest code to git

Comment: Maybe look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5R8VXnfwYw) for answers. Yocto is very flexible, so there is no standard way for what you are asking. For example, Freescale BSP  use [repo](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo) initialized [here](https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform) and [setup-environment](https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-base/blob/master/setup-environment) script.

Comment: For contribution, you can read [wiki](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Community_Guidelines)

Comment: We don't want to contribute, we want to store it locally in our servers

Comment: Make a git branch for each Yocto version for each private layers.

Comment: as mentionned by Nayfe, it is very simple by using repo & setup-environment script. It will allows you to fetch external Git repositories. So thus, you do not have to store poky, meta-openembedded... layers locally. But you have to store your own layers and managed versioning locally, in your own servers. In that way, It will be very simple to tag your local Git repositories and manifests to easily manage versions.

Comment: Have you considered using yocto projects as git submodule for your projects?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on it